# Jenkins - Execute 64bit Powershell commands

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, jenkins

I'm trying to execute a Powershell script which contains Sharepoint commands as part of my Jenkins job.

Seemingly, the Sharepoint snapin is only available to 64bit Powershell sessions. A 32bit session does not show the Sharepoint snapin.

```
64bit

PS C:\Users\user> Get-PSSnapin -Registered


Name        : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
PSVersion   : 1.0
Description : Register all administration Cmdlets for Microsoft SharePoint Server
```

Most suggestions to run a 64bit Powershell are to run from the following path. Even if I test this from a 32bit command prompt, I still get a 32bit Powershell instance

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

How can I execute 64bit (and therefore Sharepoint) Powershell commands via Jenkins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing the 64bit JRE and starting Jenkins with that (edit jenkins.xml) resolved the issue.

Comment: I did this and the web interface won't come up anymore. :/